# Google apps script sends email with attached jpg file in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

```js
function pic()
{

var userEmail = "sikrarin.pooh@gmail.com";
var firstName ="test";
var Subject = "test"
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('0B1j-ntZn6vurRkZVVEpxWmRGSlU');
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: userEmail,
subject: Subject,
attachment:[file,blob]

})
}
```

I am tryinh to send an email with a jpg file from google drive, but it doesn't work. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app), `attachments` parameter should be [`BlobSource[]`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) type and it's an array of files to send with the email.

Example from the documentation:

```
 // Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Insert any HTML content here', 'text/html', 'my_document.html');
 MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```

Check if this code will work for you:

```
function pic()
{

var userEmail = "sikrarin.pooh@gmail.com";
var firstName ="test";
var Subject = "test"
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('0B1j-ntZn6vurRkZVVEpxWmRGSlU');

MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, Subject{
attachment:[file,blob]    
});

}
```

Hope this helps!